# Conditional expanding observable chain

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The problem:

I have multiple conditions to check. Some of them result in the same observable.

The flow is following:

1. I check if a form is saved locally
2. If it is then I show a user text 1
3. If it is not then I check whether a server has this form in DB
4. If the server has it then I show text 2
5. If it does not I show text 1

Is there a way to avoid multiple conditions leading to the same result but being copy-pasted?

Now it looks like this

```
iif(
  () => this.savedLocally,
  this.showText1(),
  this.checkOnServer().pipe(
    switchMap(onServer => iif(
      () => onServer,
      this.showText2(),
      this.showText1()
    ))
  )
)
```

If there is one more condition then it has one more level with repeating `this.showText1()` in somewhere.

What I'm looking is to re-design this logic to be less repetitive.

The trick is that I need to perform three checks (next one is performed only when the previous has expected result) and all of these are asynchronous.

If it was simple `if` I would use `if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3)` but here it's not that simple. I have a strict order for checks and each check is dependent on previous result.

Comment: I don't think you can do it any more cleanly than this. There are other ways of doing it without repeating `this.showText1()` but they all wind up being more verbose and less readable.

Comment: I'll post an answer. It's going to be a long one :)

Comment: @Reactgular looking forward :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to use observables? It looks like you might be able to write this more cleanly with a simple async function

```
async () => {
    if(this.savedLocally) return this.showText1();

    const isOnServer = await this.checkOnServer();
    if(isOnserver) return this.showText2();

    const isAnotherCondition = await this.checkAnotherCondition();
    if(isAnotherCondition ) return this.showText3();

    return this.showText1();
}
```

Comment: Yes I need because I initially work with them in my Angular project and switching between Observables and Promises back and forth doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: Ah, in that case I'm sorry I can't be more helpful. Hope you find the answer you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a collection of observables where each observable determines if the next observable should be used.

If the value of an observable does not satisfy a condition, then the value of the next observable is used until the end of the collection is reached, but if an observable does satisfy a condition you don't need any of the remaining observables.

When the observable completes you need the accumulation of conditions.

You want something scalable. Allowing you to resolve a long list of conditions asynchronously, but stopping when there is no need for additional logic.

You can use a combination of a [high-order observable](https://rangle.io/blog/thinking-in-nested-streams-with-rxjs/), [reducers](https://medium.com/async-la/a-short-and-sour-guide-to-reducers-b5b54d3bb018) and a state object.

A high-order observable is an observable that emits an observable. For example;

```js
const higherOrder$ = of(of(true));
```

Let's use a state object to hold the *satisfy* condition and accumulation of values.

```js
interface State {
   // continue when value is false
   satisfy: boolean;
   // accumulation of data
   values: {[key:string]: any};
}
```

Let's start with a *default* state value.

```js
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
   satisfy: false,
   values: {
      savedLocally: false,
      onServer: false
   }
};
```

Let's define our observables that will emit values that will be accumulated.

- Each observable will emit `satisfy` and `values`.
- As long as `satisfy` is *false* the next observable will be used.
- Each `values` will be accumulated in the final result.

```js
const savedLocally$ = this.http.get(...).pipe(map(resp => ({
    satisfy: Boolean(resp), values: {savedLocally: resp}
})));

const checkOnServer$ = this.http.get(...).pipe(map(resp => ({
    satisfy: Boolean(resp), values: {onServer: resp}
})));
```

We can create a high-order observable, switch to each observable, accumate the results and stop on the first satisfied value.

Here I use the [scan()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) operator to accumate the values over each emitted value.

```js
of(savedLocally$, checkOnServer$).pipe(
   switchMap(ob$ => ob$),
   scan((acc, next) => ({
      satisfy: next.satisfy,
      values: {...acc.values, ...next.values}
   }), DEFAULT_STATE),
   filter(state => state.satisfy),
   first(),
   map(state => state.values)
).subscribe(values => console.log(values));
```

Now I don't know if this is *simpler* than what you have now, but it does scale to support a long collection of observables.

In this example, the `switchMap()` does not have access to the *previous* state values. It can be done, but is more complicated and I would need time to think of how to do it.

Comment: I've made a small test sample to test your solution, because for me it seemed to execute only the last one observable since `of` emits all of the values one by one and `switchMap` changes active subscription. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-q6vieb?devtoolsheight=60 here it can be observed in a console where `2` is print meanwhile `1` had to be (in a logic of what needed).